# Python - Open image within Tkinter from URL - not using PIL

Tags: python, image, tkinter, python-3.6

I need to display images within a tk window, but can only use these functions to do it;

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from re import findall, MULTILINE, DOTALL
from webbrowser import open as webopen
from os import getcwd
from os.path import normpath
from tkinter import *
from sqlite3 import *
from datetime import datetime
```

I was thinking that there might be some way I can do this just through tkinter's standard functions, but have yet to find any possible way.

This or I could try and find a way to convert the image to a GIF. Note that no images can be stored on the system.

The images I need to display are either JPGs or PNGs, such as [this](https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2017/10/google-io-2017-0107.jpg) one.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As is stated [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm):

> The PhotoImage class can read GIF and PGM/PPM images from files:
>
> ```
> photo = PhotoImage(file="image.gif")
>
> photo = PhotoImage(file="lenna.pgm")
> ```
>
> The PhotoImage can also read base64-encoded GIF files from strings. You can use this to embed images in Python source code (use functions in the base64 module to convert binary data to base64-encoded strings):

And as was pointed out in the comments below and [here](https://tcl.tk/software/tcltk/8.6.html) you can also use PNG images with `PhotoImage`.

Images in tkinter have to be passed in as `PhotoImage` objects to be drawn and in order to get a `PhotoImage` object, the image has to be one of the above formats.

So you will need to find a way to get the images in one of those formats using the modules you have available.

Comment: Tk 8.6 has native support for PNG images (see https://tcl.tk/software/tcltk/8.6.html), so you can read them with PhotoImage without PIL.

Comment: Updated to include

Answer (score 0):

The Tcl/Tk module `Img` allow you to load JPEG and PNG (among other formats) with PhotoImage. This module is included in some packaged distributions of Tcl/Tk. So it is worth checking whether it is installed on the computer you are using. To do so, try to load it with:

`widget.tk.eval('package require Img')`

`widget` can be any Tkinter widget.

If it returns a version number, then it is installed and loaded so you can use it and open JPEG images simply doing

`PhotoImage(file='/my/image.jpg')`